# Using CAML to filter documents by Querystring on SharePoint Online modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml, modern-pages, highlighted-content-web-part

I need to create a SharePoint modern page which will display list of documents filtered using the value in the querystring (eg .../Documents.aspx?param=2).

I have tried using "Highlighted content" web part and CAML query to filter documents, but I don't know how can I refer to the querystring value from here (please see attached image)? I have tried {Querystring.param} for the value but that does not seem to work.

Simple document library with "FilterField1=Responsibility&FilterValue1=2" in the URL does not work in modern pages.

Any idea, how can I access Querystring value in the Query text (CAML) for highlighted content web part?

[image: screenshot]